# Force SCP not to prompt for password

Tags: shell, scp

I'm writing script to test unix commands. one of them is the SCP command, where the certs are set up , so it did not ask for the password on normal scenario.

```
scp /tmp/test.txt  $userid@$hostname:$path
```

But assume scenario like certs were deleted or the user id is wrong then the script is not getting completed as scp asks for password

On the terminal

```
 scp /tmp/test.txt $userid@$hostname:$path
 Password:
```

So how can i force not to prompt for password and just fail in case it can not validate.

The scp command was stored in  a variable `line` and is executed as below

```
`$line`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically:

```
scp -o BatchMode=yes ..
```

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the scp man pages:

```
 -B      Selects batch mode (prevents asking for passwords or
         passphrases).
```